# Handling sed variables with paths in them?

Tags: shell-script, sed, quoting

I have an applescript for doing certain things, like search and replace.

```
set lol to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "VälJ Fil")
```

That chooses a file then im doing this

```
set script1 to "sed 's@id_Shops@ShopID@g'" & lol
do shell script script1
```

But sed tells me `bad flag in substitute command: '/'" number 1`

I figured it was the slashes in the path, how can i fix that?
I have tried to use `sed -i` but it gives me this error `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`

How can i do to avoid the path conflict in sed?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76785/how-to-escape-file-path-in-sed

Comment: Thats ubuntu, its different from bsd sed

Comment: @Hellobro can you please try to run your command directly? `sed 's@id_Shops@ShopID@g' script1`. Running this as your example or with directory paths works for me, must be the way file is passed to `sed`. (Also `-i` to allow in file edits.)

Answer (score 2):

You're not providing a space getween the sed program and the filename

```
set script1 to "sed 's@id_Shops@ShopID@g' " & lol
# .......................................^
```